# SQL Server 2014 sp_msforeachdb gives different results than running against individual database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

My office is changing our linked servers. As a result, I need to get a list of every single view from every database on our instance that points to the current linked server so we can know what needs replaced.

After doing some research online, I came up with this solution to get a list of all the views that reference the linked server:

1. Create a temp table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#TMP]
   (
       [DBNAME] NVARCHAR(256) NULL,
       [NAME]   NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
       [DESC]   NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
   );
   ```
2. Then, I can take advantage of the `sp_msforeachdb` procedure to iterate through each database, and store this information in the temporary table:

   ```
   DECLARE @command varchar(1000)

   SELECT @command = 'INSERT INTO #TMP SELECT ''?'' as DBName, OBJECT_NAME(object_id), definition FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE definition LIKE ''%linkedservername%'''
   EXEC sp_msforeachdb @command
   ```

When I do a `SELECT * from #TMP`, I see something fishy... the same 5 views are repeated for EVERY database. It's as if it took the first 5 views in a database that had by linked server name, and then just copied it for every database!

Things get even weirder if I modify my select command by changing `sys.sql_modules` to `[?].sys.sql_modules`; in this case, rather than getting 565 results, I only get 17!!!

Now, if I take out the `INSERT INTO #TMP"` part of the command, and run the following:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)

SELECT @command = 'SELECT ''?'' as DBName, OBJECT_NAME(object_id), definition FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE definition LIKE ''%linkedservername%'''

EXEC sp_msforeachdb @command
```

The results get even weirder! In one of my databases named "DB_Jobs", in the column for views (there isn't a column name), 3 of the 4 results returns NULL, and the last results returns "SCHTYPEMismatch". Stranger yet, in the definition column, it returns accurate results!!!

Then, if I go to the database and run this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), definition 
FROM [DB_Jobs].[sys].[sql_modules] 
WHERE definition LIKE '%linkedservername%'
```

it returns the results perfectly!

What's going on? More importantly, what can I do in my original `@command` to utilize `sp_msforeachdb` and correctly return the results I want (and include the database name for each result)?

By the way, I'm on SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sp_msforeachdb is basically a global cursor that gives you access to the each database in turn by referencing `[?]`. It doesn't execute your command on each db by default. You can see this if you run a simple

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'select db_name()'
```

For your first example, you're getting the same views because you're running the command against the same database every time. When you switch to [?].sys.sql_modules you start querying the sys.sql_modules in that database referenced by [?].

The problem with NULLs can be seen by running something like this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), definition FROM [msdb].[sys].[sql_modules] WHERE definition LIKE '%name%'
```

Run it in MSDB and you'll have a column name full of object names and a column with definitions. Run it in Master and the object names are now NULL even though you have the definitions. OBJECT_NAME() runs in the context of the current database, so you get NULLs unless you happen to have an object_id that matches, but then you're displaying the wrong object name. Definitions is directly referencing the database you want, so you still get them.

To get your query to work as you want it you just need to `USE [?]` (I'm looking for a definition like %name% because I know it will be there for testing)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#TMP](
[DBNAME] NVARCHAR(256) NULL,
[NAME]   NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
[DESC]   NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);

DECLARE @command varchar(1000)
SELECT @command = 'USE [?]; INSERT INTO #TMP SELECT ''?'' as DBName, OBJECT_NAME(object_id), definition FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE definition LIKE ''%name%'''
EXEC sp_msforeachdb @command


SELECT * FROM #TMP
```